# Using WCF REST Starter Kit with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I recently converted an ASP.NET Website to an ASP.NET MVC Application and no longer appear to have access to the WCF REST Starter Kit templates when attempting to Add > New Item... Is it possible to use the two together or is the starter kit only available within a website?

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCF REST Starter Kit templates are hosted in a IIS Host.
You will find them along with your other Web projects templates.

If you want to host them in a Win32 service, you just have to change the default host (same web.config).

[New project view http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8372/sopic1.jpg](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8372/sopic1.jpg)

(fr-FR language but you will see what i mean)